# Query WooCommerce Products based on Attribute

Tags: wordpress, attributes, woocommerce

This one's driving me nuts.. I'm trying to query and output WooCommerce products based on a specific attribute. For example, I set up an Attribute called `on`, with possible values of `yes` or `no`.

I query using the following:

```
$args = array(  
   'post_type' => 'product',  
   'meta_key' => 'pa_on',  
   'meta_value' => 'yes',  
   'posts_per_page' => -1  
);  

query_posts($args);
```

The `meta_key` is crucial perhaps; if I call it `on` I get nothing. If I call it `pa_on` (because that's how I understand WooCommerce custom attributes to be constructed) I get nothing.

However, if I try a different query and use `_featured`, which is a standard WooCommerce custom meta thingy, it returns the relevant featured posts. Help, anyone?

Comment: Seems out of bounds for StackOverflow. This isn't an explicit PHP question. It's specific to WordPress, and therefore, the post should be migrated to wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks Chris - I'll leave it hanging and if a moderator moves the thread, so be it :)

Answer (score 10):

I know this is an old one, but just in case someone stumbles upon it like I did today -- Woocommerce (I'm using v2.6.2) appears to store these custom attributes as taxonomies.

I suspect the correct args for the original question would look like this:

```
  $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'tax_query' => array(
      array(
        'taxonomy' => 'pa_on',
        'field'    => 'name',
        'terms'    => 'yes'
      )
    )
  );
```

Using the appropriate values for my installation, it solved my problem.

Answer (score 4):

For new woocommerce use:

```
$attribute = 'on';
$value = 'yes';
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'tax_query' => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy'      => 'pa_' . $attribute,
        'terms'         => $value,
        'field'         => 'slug',
        'operator'      => 'IN'
        )
    )
);
```

Answer (score 3):

If product attribute is saved as specific product attribute (i.e. not global), then you can't query it as taxonomy, instead you can use this snippet (copied from http://snippet.fm/snippets/query-woocommerce-products-product-specific-custom-attribute/):

```
// Set custom attribute name and value to search for
$attribute_name  = 'color';
$attribute_value = 'green';

$serialized_value = serialize( 'name' ) . serialize( $attribute_name ) . serialize( 'value' ) . serialize( $attribute_value ); // extended version: $serialized_value = serialize( $attribute_name ) . 'a:6:{' . serialize( 'name' ) . serialize( $attribute_name ) . serialize( 'value' ) . serialize( $attribute_value ) . serialize( 'position' );
$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'product',
    'post_status'    => 'any',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'orderby'        => 'title',
    'order'          => 'ASC',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => '_product_attributes',
            'value'   => $serialized_value,
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        ),
    ),
);
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
    $loop->the_post();
    // do stuff here... e.g. get_the_ID()
}
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Answer (score 0):

Guess what you need is a query with meta_query value set:

```
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'product',
'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key' => 'pa_on',
        'value' => 'yes',
        'compare' => '='
    )
)
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

You can learn more about those here:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters

Comment: Thanks Kriesi, but I'm afraid that doesn't work either :( I normally use this format for querying and had already tried it - you'd think this would work anywhere in a theme, right?! I'm obviously looking at WooCommerce attributes in the wrong way - there's something amiss here..

Comment: do you know how to do it with sql query raw ?